# #pragma warning is not suppressing a warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor, pragma

One of my .cpp files is generating warning C4275 due to a 3rd-party header I `#include`... (the warning is triggered due to a DLL-export class inheriting from a non-DLL-export class as far as I can tell).

I added the line:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4275)
```

As the first line of my .cpp file and yet the warning is still being generated. This is on VC++ 2008, and no PCH is in use.

Why is my `#pragma` not working, and (other than changing the 3rd-party code) how can I address this?

Comment: any chance your using openmp?(only place i've ever seen/used #pragma)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate a preprocessed file and you'll probably find that some other header file's re-enabling the warning.

Comment: To save some frustration: In Visual Studio 2005 and 2012 using the /P flag causes the warning pragma to be ignored, e.g. `/P /D "NOMINMAX"` and
`#pragma warning(disable:4005)
#define NOMINMAX`
results in warning C4005.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this particular warning, but in Visual Studio, you can disable specific warnings via project properties (i.e., not pragma).  Disabling them that way seems to be "stronger" than disabling them via a pragma.  You might do that for just the one file you're using.

Of course, warnings frequently tell you something useful, so this would really be a last resort.

Comment: That doesn't work either. In my case I found juggling the `#includes` made the warning disappear - this time - but I still wonder what circumstances the `#pragma` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone stumbles across this in a case similar to mine:

If you get the warning for a template code, you need to disable that warning before the template include rather than the code which uses it.

Example:

```
// Disable the warning for size_t to int conversion which would cause a problem on 
// 64 bit systems if the first container had more than 2^32 elements. Disabling it 
// here is considered safe since it is impossible for the source container used in 
// this class ever have that many elements.
#pragma warning(disable : 4267)
#include <myLib/myTemplateDefs.h>
#pragma warning(default : 4267)

// Code which uses the template goes here
```

In our case, this was an acceptable solution since the containers involved stored column names of database tables.